# Calling methods implemend by mixins without super

Tags: javascript, inheritance, mixins

I want to have a mixin class, which expects the concrete class to define a certain method. Something like:

```
function BaseMixin(Base) {
  class Mixin extends Base {
    doSomething() {
      this.onSomethingDone()
    }
  }

  return Mixin
}
```

At the same time I'd allow optional mixins which potentially also declare such method. The end result is that the concrete class and each mixin needs to call `super.onSomethingDone` and because the order in which mixins are applied can change, they must also check that method exists:

```
function SecondaryMixin(Base) {
  class Mixin extends Base {
    onSomethingDone() {
      if (super.onSomethingDone)
        super.onSomethingDone()

      // stuff specific to SecondaryMixin
    }
  }

  return Mixin
}

class ConcreteClass extends SecondaryMixin(BaseMixin(HTMLElement)) {
  doSomething() {
    if (super.onSomethingDone)
      super.onSomethingDone()

    // stuff specific to ConcreteClass
  }
}
```

This is tedious and error-prone. Instead, is it possible to only have implementors do their `specific stuff` and in the `BaseMixin` somehow iterate and call all implementations of `onSomethingDone` from all applied mixins?

```
function BaseMixin(Base) {
  class Mixin extends Base {
    doSomething() {
      for (let onSomethingDone of getAllImplementationsThereof()) {
        onSomethingDone()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just FWIW, those wouldn't normally be called mixins. Those are optionally-applied superclasses. Mixins don't participate in inhertiance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement `getAllImplementations` like this:

```js
function getAllImplementationsOf(cls, methodName) {
    let fns = [];

    cls = Object.getPrototypeOf(cls);

    while (cls) {
        if (cls.prototype && cls.prototype.hasOwnProperty(methodName))
            fns.push(cls.prototype[methodName]);
        cls = Object.getPrototypeOf(cls);
    }

    return fns;
}

//


function FirstMixin(Base) {
    return class Mixin extends Base {
        work() {
            console.log('first')
        }
    }
}

function SecondMixin(Base) {
    return class Mixin extends Base {
        work() {
            console.log('second')
        }
    }
}

class Base {
}

class ConcreteClass extends FirstMixin(SecondMixin(Base)) {

    work() {
        for (let fn of getAllImplementationsOf(this.constructor, 'work'))
            fn.call(this);
        console.log('done!')
    }
}

new ConcreteClass().work();
```

That being said, I'm not sure `extends` is the right tool to implement mixins, exactly because of this type of problems. I'd rather look into proxies.

Comment: I liked your original implementation better. But both work.